# Healpy map2alm and alm2map inconsistency?

Tags: python, healpy

I'm just starting to work with Healpy and have noticed that if I use a map to get alm's and then use those alm's to generate a new map, I do not get the map I started with.  Here's what I'm looking at:

```python
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
nside = 2 # healpix nside parameter
m = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(nside)) # create a map to test
alm = hp.map2alm(m) # compute alm's
new_map = hp.alm2map(alm, nside) # create new map from computed alm's

# Let's look at two maps
print(m)
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47] # as expected

print(new_map)
[-23.30522233 -22.54434515 -21.50906755 -20.09203749 -19.48841773
-18.66392484 -16.99593867 -16.789984   -15.14587061 -14.57960049
-13.4403252  -13.35992138 -10.51368725 -10.49793946 -10.1262039
-8.6340571   -7.41789272  -6.87712224  -5.75765487  -3.75121764
-4.35825512  -1.6221964   -1.03902923  -0.41478954   0.52480646
 2.34629955   2.1511705    2.40325268   5.39576497   5.38390848
 5.78324832   7.24779083   8.4915595    9.0047257   10.15179735
 12.1306303   12.62672772  13.4512206   15.11920678  15.32516145
 16.96927483  17.53554496  18.67482024  18.75522407  20.42078855
 21.18166574  22.21694334  23.6339734 ] # not what I was expecting
```

As you can see, new_map doesn't match the input map, m.  I imagine there's some subtlety to these functions that I'm missing.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a different result:

`print(new_map)
      [  0.15859344,   0.91947062,   1.95474822,   3.37177828,
         4.01808325,   4.84257613,   6.51056231,   6.71651698,
         8.36063036,   8.92690049,  10.06617577,  10.1465796 ,
        12.98620654,  13.00668621,  13.3736899 ,  14.87056857,
        16.08200108,  16.62750343,  17.74223892,  19.75340803,
        19.13441288,  21.8704716 ,  22.45363877,  23.07787846,
        24.01747446,  25.83896755,  25.6438385 ,  25.89592068,
        28.89565876,  28.88853415,  29.28314212,  30.7524165 ,
        31.9914533 ,  32.50935137,  33.65169114,  35.63525597,
        36.13322869,  36.95772158,  38.62570775,  38.83166242,
        40.47577581,  41.04204594,  42.18132122,  42.26172504,
        43.88460433,  44.64548151,  45.68075911,  47.09778917]`

Older versions of `healpy` were automatically removing a constant offset from the map before transformation, better to update `healpy` to the last version.

The residual difference is related to the fact the pixelization introduces an error, this error is larger at low nside.

Comment: So if there were a uniform monopole contribution across the whole map, it would subtract it off before the transformation?

Comment: In old versions of healpy, it was doing that.